# Request for references: Moral values as the result of minimizing friction

Tags: ethics

Is there a name for a position on the origins of morality that is compatible with the following:

- "Good" and "bad" are not intrinsic properties of actions.
- The purpose making a moral judgment is to encourage or discourage the certain actions.
- The convergence of a moral judgment for a given action is faster when that action causes a bigger disruption in the daily life of the individual/group, that is, the judgement of very disruptive actions is agreed upon faster than the judgment of actions that cause little or no disruption.

Background: I was wondering how a individual/group could arrive to a set of "values" -- which I think of as shortcuts or predefined rules -- that help keep stability in the daily functioning of the individual or group.

My current thinking is that morality arose as a means to minimize friction/disruption within an individual -- individuals judging their own actions --, or within a group.

Over time, the judgements accumulate and the individual/groups starts creating categories and quick rules on how to classify actions that have not been encountered before. These "quick rules" or shortcuts is roughly what we call "values". The divergence of values among individuals/groups would appear naturally as a consequence of the differences in experiences.

I don't know the literature on morality and what I'm asking here is just some pointers to literature that disproves this idea of morality as friction/disruption minimizer or that supports it.

Comment: Without attempting to name your thinking, I don't think it produces enough morality for abolitionists to overcome slavery or for revolutionaries to justify a revolution.  These movements are only possible with access to a universal morality that binds winners as well as losers.

Comment: This sounds like a variant of [negative utilitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_utilitarianism)

Comment: @elliotsvensson I disagree, I think that as long as humans can empathize with other humans, the constant friction/disruption caused by guilt, plus the shaming of others would be enough to drive those "revolutions". I can't prove this but I think humans will undertake dramatic actions in order to keep a self-image that let's them sleep at night, including helping strangers.

Comment: @Conifold Wow, I never heard about this before, I think it's exactly that.